# How to launch multiple instances of a console application in separate app domains?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, appdomain

I have a console application A and console application B.
Is it possible to launch multiple instances of B from A. It is important that each instance of console application B to be run in its own app domain. 
If it is possible, how to do that ?

Comment: Buy I need multiple instances of appB and each to start in its own app domain.

Comment: -1: Each new process have its own AppDomain so Process.Start should be fine, but it looks like you are looking for something else. Unfortunately it is very unclear what exactly you are looking for and why separate process do not work for you - please edit your question to make it clear if separte processes ok or you need single process with multiple AppDomains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible. The steps to take are:

1. Application A creates a new application domain.
2. Execute console application B in the new application domain.
3. Unload the new application domain after console application B has finished executing.

A very simple example is:

```
var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("a name");

appDomain.ExecuteAssembly("ConsoleApplicationB.exe"); //Update with the path to consolse application B.          

AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
```

Note that this is the simplest example I could make. Choose the [AppDomain.CreateDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.createdomain.aspx) overload that better suites your needs.

Note that [AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.executeassembly.aspx) is blocking. You will notice this when you run the example. Console application A will block until application B exits. You will have to do this asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

A console can be associated with only *one process*. I don't see a way other that `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("B")`

See    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Where did you read that? Processes can share the same console either by using AllocConsole or by creating child processes. This is the same with application domains. The new application domain can execute a console application that will share the console with the main application domain.

Answer (score 1):

@I4V

I think you mixed that up. A *process* can be associated with only **one** *console*.

That means a process can communicate only with **one** console (in|out|err), in ligher terms, a process can **not** *own* more than one console windows.

That said, **more than one**  *process* can communicate with one console. Idealy well synchronized processes.

There are of course some workarounds that allow one process to have multiple console windows (WinTTY)